# Holaa tengo un problema con una consulta sql

Tags: php, html, mysql

**Tengo un formulario donde quiero guardar datos a mi base de datos pero antes de guardar quiero que me muestre si la fecha que estoy ingresado por input ya existe y si existe que me muestre los valores el codigo ya tengo echo y el alert ya me funciona solo que en la consulta sql no se como agarrar el valor que estoy ingresado en mi fecha y compararlo en mi consulta sql**

```
<form action="add_juicio.php" method="POST" name="form">
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label>Fecha de Inicio</label>
                <input type="date" name="fecha_add" required class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label>Dia</label>
                <select name="dia" class="form-control" required>
                    <option value="">SELECCIONE UNA OPCION</option>
                    <option value="LUNES">LUNES</option>
                    <option value="MARTES">MARTES</option>
                    <option value="MIERCOLES">MIERCOLES</option>
                    <option value="JUEVES">JUEVES</option>
                    <option value="VIERNES">VIERNES</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-1">
               <label>Hora</label>
               <input type="time" name="hora" required class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-1">
              <label>Nro Causa</label>
              <input type="text" name="causa" required class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-1">
             <label>Año</label>
             <input type="text" name="ano" required class="form-control">
              </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                <label>Caratula</label>
                <input type="text" name="caratula" required class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label>Presidente</label>
                <input type="text" name="presidente" required class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label>Titular 1</label>
                <input type="text" name="titularuno" required class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label>Titular 2</label>
                <input type="text" name="titulardos" required class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label>Fiscal</label>
                <input type="text" name="fiscal" required class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label>Defensa</label>
                <input type="text" name="defensa" required class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label>Resultado</label>
                <input type="text" name="resultado" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label>Motivo</label>
                <input type="text" name="motivo" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <label>Observacion</label>
                <input type="text" name="obs" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label>Nueva Fecha</label>
                <input type="date" name="fecha_act" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
              <br>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" name="guardar" value="guardar" data-target="#modal-default">Guardar</button>
            </div> 

            <div class="modal fade" id="modal-default">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">VERIFICAR FECHA Y HORA DE JUICIO ORAL</h4>
                  </div>
                  <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT * from coordinacion WHERE fecha_add = 'valor de mi fecha'";
                    $query = $connection->prepare($sql);
                    $query->execute();
                  ?>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>FECHA</th>
                          <th>HORA</th>
                          <th>CAUSA</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <?php foreach ($query->fetchAll() as $file ) {  ?>
                         <tr>
                          <td><?php echo $file['fecha_add']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $file['hora']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $file['causa']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php }  ?>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="guardar" value="guardar" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

*mi consulta sql es esta SELECT * from coordinacion WHERE fecha_add = 'valor de mi fecha'
ahi donde dice valor de la fecha es lo que quiero que me estire la fecha que puse en mi input antes de guardarlo*

Comment: Vamos a ver si entendí... Exactamente lo que quieres es: Que al momento de guardar esos valores, consultar si la fecha ya está en esa tabla y en caso de que SI ESTE, que te traiga ese valor, de lo contrario que guarde la fecha. Es así?

Answer (score 0):

Entendiendo que quieres hacer esto en tu mismo archivo, yo veo dos opciones:

1. Si deseas programar este comportamiento exclusivamente con PHP de lado del servidor, te adelanto que no te será posible sin mandar el formulario, puesto que debes enviar el valor del campo primero al servidor para que tenga algo con lo que hacer la consulta. En ese caso yo pondría un `if(isset($_POST["guardar"])){}` que comprobase que se ha enviado primeramente ese valor pulsando el botón de guardar y luego metería dentro el `foreach` que te saca la fila de la tabla.
2. Si quieres valerte de opciones de lado del cliente, puedes hacer esa consulta al servidor con Javascript (objeto `XMLHttpRequest()`) o bien con jQuery (`$.ajax()` o `$.get()`), que es como un atajo para el primero). Para ello primero deberías crear un archivo consulta.php al que le pasarías por parámetros el timestamp y que te debería devolver en formato JSON o XML el resultado de la consulta. Luego, según el resultado, ya haces lo que tú consideres.

Un ejemplo de esto último (como yo lo haría, que no soy ningún experto en el tema) sería el siguiente:

```
$.get("consulta.php", {
    timestamp: $("#elementoQueContieneElTimestamp").val();
    //si no hay ningún elemento que contenga el timestamp antes de mandarlo, 
    //te recomiendo que construyas el timestamp usando el objeto Data() de Javascript
    //también puedes usar librerías como MomentJS que te simplifican mucho el trabajo con fechas.*/
}, function(result){
    if(result == true){
        //lo que necesites hacer, como pasar a una página "success.php"
    } else {
        //mostrar un alert() y otras acciones relacionadas con el error.
        //puedes también incluir en caso de false un objeto con más datos, por ejemplo "data".
        //puedes acceder a esos datos usando "result.data"
    }
}, "JSON");
```

No sé si esto responde 100% a tu pregunta, pero espero haber ayudado un poco.

Comment: Desde ya muchas gracias por tu respuesta. y se que tengo que mandar primero el formulario sin eso no podre hacer  nada. pero estaba pensado en duplicar ese valor que estoy ingresado en mi input y ese valor duplicado igualar a una $variabel y ahi usar  ese variable para consultarlo pero no se como hacerlo soy novato no se si es posible eso tambien

Comment: Creo que no necesitas comprobarlo en realidad. O sea, si tu consulta te está devolviendo algún resultado es que, efectivamente hay un registro cuyo campo `fecha_add` se corresponde con el valor buscado. De lo contrario, te dolvería un resultset vacío. La respuesta de @Amilcar Angeles en ese caso te podría valer. O quizá no estamos terminando de entender lo que pretendes conseguir.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que con este corto código puedes resolver tu problema:

```
<?php
//Conexion a la base de datos, si ya lo tienes omitelo.
$conexion=mysql_connect("host","usuario","contraseña");
mysql_select_db("BBDD",$conexion);

////Obteniendo registros de la base de datos a traves de una consulta SQL
$fechaExiste="SELECT * from coordinacion WHERE fecha_add = 'valor de tu fecha'";
$resultado=mysql_query($fechaExiste,$conexion); 

if (!empty(resultado) {
    $VariableAMostrar = $resultado;
}
    else {
            //aquí va el comando SQL o lo que sea para guardar tus datos
        }
?>
```